# Cannot resolve method setHasOptionsMenu in android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, optionmenu

I try to used `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in my activity but i get an error. "cannot resolve method setHasOptionsMenu".

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.job_status_option_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete example. In particular, you are missing the class which contains the methods you have shown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to remove `setHasOptionMenu(true)` from your `onCreate()` method, and change the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.job_status_option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should place this method call inside the oncreateview of fragment if you use fragments inside activity. Or else you don't have to use this invocation inside activity.

Comment: i am not using fragment, i am using activity

Comment: Then why are you invoking this method?

Comment: @JihinRaju Activity does not have a method as setHasOptionsMenu(), this method belongs to Fragment class. You don't have to call that method. onCreateOptionsMenu is enough for Activities.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese I have try at onCreateView but still unresolved